# Django-cms. Change plugin appearance in structure mode

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I've made a Django-CMS plugin which shows a gallery of images. But when I look to it in edit-structure mode I see only the count of images in the current gallery. Like that.

[image]

Is there any way, to make it show a thumbnails of pictures in that mode?

Answer (score 1):

In structure mode, all plugins are reduce to a single line of text. To see their content, switch to content edit mode.

Comment: it's a pity. :( Maybe you can give me some advice how to change content edit mode?

Comment: Click on "content" in the toolbar, see http://i.imgur.com/zj1Pb5l.png

Then it should look a bit like http://i.imgur.com/GtkkqK2.png

Comment: I see only the name of the gallerу I have chosen, but I'd like to see the pictures from that gallery too.

Comment: In structure mode, that's all you'll ever see (by design), to see the pictures, switch to content mode (or exit edit mode completely).